# How do I eliminate the error "Timestamp Mismatch"?

Tags: timestamp

I see a lot of related questions, but none that quite handle the following:

System: Ubuntu/Wordpress 4.9.8  Civi 4.7.23

I'm about to upgrade Civi but the error about "Timestamp mismatch" is making me worry.

The MySQL time stamp is correct and matches "date" on the server.

The Wordpress time setting is correct and matches "date" on the server.

The PHP time setting as exposed in phpinfo() is correct although it of course doesn't spell out a time, just a timezone, which is correct.

So why is this error persisting?

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE - IS FIXED]

I fixed this by revisiting WordPress's settings and changing the Timezone setting from "UTC -5" to "Chicago".  Both of these settings reflect the same time zone, so why these two settings are seen as different I can't say, but Civi no longer complains.

So I guess the lesson is: if you want to get rid of this error and you're showing no actual disagreement on timezone between the server, PHP or WordPress, go to WordPress and pick the timezone that is named for the city you're aiming at.

Hope that helps someone.